# Google Chrome weird crash

Tags: macos, google-chrome, crash

im using Google Chrome for years and i never experienced like this before.

im using chrome for a while without problems(several tabs open), then i open a new tab and google disables everything. can't close tab, can't open new tab. but i can change between tabs.

is there anyone have a problem like this before ?

Comment: Does it always happen with the same web site (or directly when creating an empty new tab)?

Comment: it changes time by time.

Comment: i cant enter ebay.com today. but 2 days ago i can